# Marshal URLs for hierarchical relationships with Flask-restful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have problems getting the flask-restful marshal_with function to do what I want. Basically I have 4 endpoints to access two hierarchical entities (parents and children).

```
class Parent(db.Model):
  name = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
  children = db.relationship(Child)

class Child(db.Model):
  name = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
  parent = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('parents.name'))
```

Parent resources:

```
parent_marshal_template = {
  'name': fields.String,
  'children': fields.Url('children-endpoint', attribute='name')
}

class Parents(Resource):  # /parents
  @marshal_with(parent_marshal_template)
  def get(self):
    return list_of_parents

class Parent(Resource):  # /parents/<str:name> (parent-endpoint)
  @marshal_with(parent_marshal_template)
  def get(self, name):
    return single_parent_with_name
```

Child resources:

```
child_marshal_template = {
  'name': fields.String,
  'parent': fields.Url('parent-endpoint', attribute='name')
}

class Children(Resource):  # /parents/<str:parent>/children (children-endpoint)
  @marshal_with(child_marshal_template)
  def get(self, parent):
    return list_of_children_of_parent

class Child(Resource):  # /parents/<str:parent>/children/<str:name>
  @marshal_with(child_marshal_template)
  def get(self, parent, name):
    return single_child_with_name
```

`parent_marshal_template` should return the URL to get all children of this parent for the 'children' key. `child_marshal_template` should return the URL to it's parent for the 'parent' key. Both throw errors that say that I forgot to specify values. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the resource name.

```py
app.add_resource(Parent,"/parent",endpoint='parent-endpoint')
app.add_resource(Child,"/child",endpoint='child-endpoint')
```

Once you add this, you can use the `Field.Url` function to point to the api endpoint.

```py
parent_marshal_template = {
  'name': fields.String,
  'children': fields.Url('children-endpoint', attribute='name')
}

child_marshal_template = {
  'name': fields.String,
  'parent': fields.Url('parent-endpoint', attribute='name')
}
```